# Download json object as json file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am looking for ways to download a stringfied json object as file..

I do have one solution as presented in this fiddle example:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/49daff8r/)

My working version looks like this

**HTML**

```
    From data attribute of span:
    <span id="a-data"></span>
    <span id="obj-data" data-obj2='{"obj-1": "text-1","obj-2": "text-2","obj-3": "text-3"}'></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var obj = $("#obj-data").data("obj2");
    var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
    $('<a href="data:' + data + '" download="data.json">Download Me</a>').appendTo("#a-data");
```

I'd prefer if I could use this HTML. could you suggest a way to approach that?

```
From data attribute of self:
<div id="data" data-obj='{"obj-1": "text-1","obj-2": "text-2","obj-3": "text-3"}'>
    Download Me
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try substituting `"application/json"` for `"text/json"` , calling `.click()` on `DOM` element `a` , removing `a` at `click` handler

```js
$("#data").click(function() {
  $("<a />", {
    "download": "data.json",
    "href" : "data:application/json," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($(this).data().obj))
  }).appendTo("body")
  .click(function() {
     $(this).remove()
  })[0].click()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="data" data-obj='{"obj-1": "some text","obj-2": "text-2","obj-3": "text-3"}'>
    Download Me
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kda2rdLy/

Comment: for some reason this seems to remove spaces in json string when the data file is opened

Comment: This object {"key":"some text"} ends up like this {"key":"sometext"} in this example .. "some text" is not supposed to merge into "sometext"

Comment: @GRowing See updated post. Wrapped `$(this).data().obj` in `encodeURIComponent()` jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kda2rdLy/

Comment: ahh,, yes,, you're right. thanks for borrowing your eyes to me :)

Comment: Had `encodeURIComponenet()` in `js` at OP ; neglected to included that portion, here , at original post above

Comment: This seems to not work for large json files. Which is the max size that can be embedded?